# Where to find documentation on BCrypt for .NET?

Tags: c#, documentation, bcrypt, bcrypt.net

I used NuGet to get the BCrypt library and it's installed properly. Now I'd like to read about it and how to use it, yet I can't seem to find any documentation.

Even searching for the libraries namespace yielded no results:

```
DevOne.Security.Cryptography.BCrypt
```

Any suggestions on where to find some examples, or even plain old documentation? I'm using C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no official documentation, other than [this page](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx).

That being said, you can easily look at the [source code](http://derekslager.com/blog/attachment.ashx/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono/BCrypt.cs), as there are only a couple of public routines in the API.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but it's still the first result on Google for "BCrypt.NET documentation".

Therefore, I'd like to expand on the answer and say the latest download of BCrypt.NET has documentation included in the release.  Specifically, "BCrypt.Net.XML".  Strange that it's stored in an XML file, but it explains the work factor and various methods succinctly.