# How to move successfully username login details to another database

Tags: database, passwords, phpmyadmin, password-encryption

I have inherited a site with 3000 users.  I want to import all of these users into a new site's database that is based on Doplphin (Boonex).

I have attempted to import the data.  User data imports successfully, but not their passwords.

All the passwords are encrypted.

In the old database i am not sure what type of encryption has been used, at a guess i think they are not MD5.

This is the format of one of the passwords currently stored in the Old database.

```
$2a$10$M/HQVUTyxrdbiwNjokJoUOIbUAK71yvYXKPe1YdFgS2I3Pw6Ojlju
```

How can I get these passwords to work correctly when imported into the new database?

Is there any method I need to know about to import passwords into a new database that is working within a different framework?

Answer (score 3):

That password is `BCrypt` hashed. (i can tell from the `$2a$10$...`)

Hopefully your platform has a:

```
BCrypt.CheckPassword(savedHash, enteredPassword);
```

function.

---

From [my answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10933491/12597):

A BCrypt hash ***string*** looks like:

```
$2a$10$M/HQVUTyxrdbiwNjokJoUOIbUAK71yvYXKPe1YdFgS2I3Pw6Ojlju
$==$==$======================-------------------------------
```

Where

- `2a`: Algorithm Identifier (BCrypt)
- `10`: Cost Factor (1,024 rounds)
- `M/HQVUTyxrdbiwNjokJoUO`: OpenBSD-Base64 encoded salt (22 characters, 16 bytes)
- `IbUAK71yvYXKPe1YdFgS2I3Pw6Ojlju`: OpenBSD-Base64 encoded hash (31 characters, 24 bytes)

> **Edit**: i just noticed these words fit exactly. i had to share:
>
> ```
> $2a$10$TwentytwocharactersaltThirtyonecharacterspasswordhash
> $==$==$======================-------------------------------
> ```

---

But **BCrypt** was created by guys who were working on OpenBSD. **OpenBSD** already defines a format for their password file:

**$**`[HashAlgorithmIdentifier]`**$**`[AlgorithmSpecificData]`

This means that the *"bcrypt specification"* is inexorably linked to the OpenBSD password file format. And whenever anyone creates a *"bcrypt hash"* they *always* convert it to an ISO-8859-1 string of the format:

**$**`2a`**$**`[Cost]`**$**`[Base64Salt][Base64Hash]`

A few important points:

- `2a` is the alogithm identifier

  - `1`: MD5
  - `2`: early bcrypt, which had confusion over which encoding passwords are in (obsolete)
  - `2a`: current bcrypt, which specifies passwords as UTF-8 encoded
- *Cost* is a cost factor used when computing the hash. The "current" value is 10, meaning the internal key setup goes through 1,024 rounds

  - **10: 2<sup>10</sup> = 1,024 iterations**
  - 11: 2<sup>11</sup> = 2,048 iterations
  - 12: 2<sup>12</sup> = 4,096 iterations
- the base64 algorithm used by the OpenBSD password file is not the same Base64 encoding that **everybody else** uses; they have their own:

  ```
  Regular Base64 Alphabet: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/
      BSD Base64 Alphabet: ./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
  ```

  So any implementations of bcrypt cannot use any built-in, or standard, base64 library

---

Armed with this knowledge, you can now verify a password `correctbatteryhorsestapler` against the saved hash:

```
$2a$12$mACnM5lzNigHMaf7O1py1O3vlf6.BA8k8x3IoJ.Tq3IB/2e7g61Km
```

Comment: Thanks so now i know that they are BCrypt hash. Do you have any advice of how i can get these password to work in a different database and environment?

Comment: You have to use BCrypt to *verify* their passwords. You will never know the user's current passwords (which is the entire point: nobody should ever be able to see anyone's password). In your new system you will have to get ahold of a BCrypt implementation. When the Boonex system asks you to validate a set of credentials (i.e. *username*, *password*) you will use BCrypt to verify the password.