# Understanding BCrypt

Tags: php, hash, passwords, salt, bcrypt

I understand how to write PHP code to successfully utilize BCrypt. So, **I don't need help getting it to work**.

Instead, I need help understanding how in the heck BCrypt magically works!

In [this code](https://gist.github.com/jonathancadepowers/8257245), on line 15, in order to verify if the login password == the original (and now hashed/salted) password, it looks to me like you are just (a) creating a new hashed/salted value using the login password and the original (and now hashed/salted) password, and then (b) comparing the value created in (a) to the original (and now hashed/salted) password. **I don't understand how these can ever be equal, but they are!**

For example, let's say a user signs up with a password of **test**, which let's say (for simplicity) gets hashed/salted to **1234**.

A day later, the user tries to login (using **1234**), and we need to authenticate them. To do so, we execute the code on line 15. This means that we do the following:

```
crypt("test", "1234") == "1234"
```

How in the heck does hashing/salting **test** with a NEW SALT VALUE (in this case **1234**) result in a match?

At this point, this question is mostly just a brain teaser for me. ;)

Comment: That salt generation is utter crap.

Comment: Not an answer, but really stop using those crappy 3rd party codes. And use the native [password hashing API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) in PHP.

Comment: Have a look at this answer, I think it will make you understand better how a bcrypt hash is composed : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10933491/165055

Comment: Instead of hacking code together, use the [password functions](http://php.net/password) introduced with PHP 5.5 ([compat code](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) available for PHP >= 5.3.7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bcrypt hashing depends on the password and the salt and (like any hashing algorithm) it is fully deterministic.

If the password and the salt are the same, the result will be the same.
If either the password or the salt changes, the result will change.

When you use `crypt($password, $hashedPassword)`, bcrypt is not using the hashed password as the salt. It is extracting the salt from the hashed password and then using that.

The result of `crypt` is `$2y$number$salt-hashedpassword`, so if you take the beginning of the hashed password you get the original salt.

Note how the result of `crypt($password, $salt)` starts with the value of `$salt`.

Comment: Very good answer. I used a few times but did not understand how it worked.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. It breaks it down perfectly. My brain no longer hurts. Thanks!