# Regular expression to find bcrypt hash?

Tags: regex, hash

I am looking to find bcrypt hash string using regex (in PowerGrep), in a database.

Tried this regex:

```
{?A-Za-z_0-9.{60}}?
```

But no match was found. Bcrypt hash is 60 characters length, and starts with "$2y$".

Example:

```
$2y$15$nK/B6u765645/lo0867h56546v/BnH5U5g45Aj67u67nMVtrhryt6
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**:

Since beside the `y` value there might be `a` or `b`, you may use

```
^\$2[ayb]\$.{56}$
```

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/vvqI6F/1). **Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `\$` - a literal `$` char (it should be escaped in a regex pattern to match a literal `$` char, else, it will denote the end of string)
- `2` - a `2` char
- `[ayb]` - a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) matching any single char out of the specified set
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `.{56}` - any 56 chars other than line break chars (if not POSIX compliant regex engine is used, else, it will match any chars; to match any chars in common NFA engines, replace `.` with `[\s\S]` or use a corresponding `DOTALL` flag)
- `$` - end of string.

**Original answer**

Your regex - `{?A-Za-z_0-9.{60}}?` - contains ranges not inside a character class `[...]`, but inside optional curly braces, and thus they present sequences of literal characters. See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jD7aL3/2) to see what I mean.

You can use the following regex:

```
^\$2y\$.{56}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jD7aL3/1)

The `^` matches the start of string, `\$2y\$` matches `$2y$` literally (as `$` is a special character and needs escaping) and `.{56}` is the rest 56 characters.

Answer (score 27):

Just as an addition to the answer above from @stribizhev. The bcrypt hashes you might encounter out there in the wild come in a few varieties, so you may have to modify the regex to catch all of them. The variations are as follows:

The "Algorithm Identifier" portion of the hash may include:

- `"2"` - the first revision of BCrypt, which suffers from a minor security flaw and is generally not used anymore.
- `"2a"` - some implementations suffered from a very rare security flaw.
- `"2y"` - format specific to the crypt_blowfish BCrypt implementation, identical to "2a" in all but name.
- `"2b"` - latest revision of the official BCrypt algorithm

```js
^\$2[ayb]\$.{56}$
```

seems to work for me

see here for the breakdown of a bcrypt hash: [Can someone explain how BCrypt verifies a hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393803/can-someone-explain-how-bcrypt-verifies-a-hash)

Comment: I've updated your regex to be a bit more precise: `^\$2[ayb]\$[0-9]{2}\$[A-Za-z0-9\.\/]{53}$`.  This checks for the cost value after the version identifier and refines the character class for the salt and hash bits.  Depending on your interpreter, you may not need to escape the `/` in the regex.  For the cost value, this simply checks the format, not whether the value is valid (valid values are 4-31, inclusive).

Comment: Over time, the length could get longer than 60 if you are bcrypting using php's new password_hash function. For this reason, a regex of `^\$2[ayb]\$.+$` may be more appropriate.

Comment: Rand, [ayb] should be optional to support the oldest version: `^\$2[ayb]?\$...`

Answer (score 10):

Use this:

```
^\$2[aby]?\$\d{1,2}\$[.\/A-Za-z0-9]{53}$
```

Explanation:

- `\$2[aby]?\$` - matches the algorithm used. Valid values are 2, 2a, 2y and 2b
- `\d{1,2}\$` - matches the cost, or how many rounds, which is an integer between 4 and 31 (inclusive)
- `[.\/A-Za-z0-9]{53}` - matches the salt and the hash, with the salt making up the first 22 characters, and the hashed password making up the last 31

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia, bcrypt hashes follow the following format:

```
$2a$10$N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMyeIjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy
\__/\/ \____________________/\_____________________________/
 Alg Cost      Salt                        Hash
```

Where valid values for each segment are:

- Alg: `2`, `2a`, `2b`, `2x` or `2y`
- Cost: 4-31 (zero-padded to 2 digits)
- Salt: `./0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` x 22
- Hash: `./0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` x 31

Therefore, a comprehensive regex would look something like the following:

```
^[$]2[abxy]?[$](?:0[4-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[$][./0-9a-zA-Z]{53}$
```